# cmake add_custom_command failure, target gets deleted

Tags: c++, cmake, gnu-make

I am building a test executable using CMake. During the build process, I would like to run the executable, which returns whether the tests pass or not. If not, I would like the build to fail. However, when I use `add_custom_command(... POST_BUILD ... )`, and use a `Makefile` generator, the test executable will be deleted (explain in this question: [Why does GNU make delete a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588550/why-does-gnu-make-delete-a-file)).

Is there a way to have CMake treat the executable as a `.PRECIOUS`, or otherwise change the CMakeLists.txt such that the executable doesn't get deleted if the tests fail?

For reference, my CMakeList.txt looks like the following (simplified from actual):

```
add_executable(UnitTest unittest.cpp)
add_custom_command(TARGET UnitTest POST_BUILD COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:UnitTest>)
```

Comment: You could copy the executable somewhere else where CMake won't delete it.

Comment: Is it alright if the test runs every time you build even if it succeeded previously or the executable and its dependencies did not change?

Comment: @Florian: Given question explicitely says that `I would like the build to fail.`, so just ignoring the error isn't suitable for the asker needs. Also, the question you reference as duplicate operates on configuration (`cmake`) stage, given question operates on build(`make`) stage.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry, didn't see the part of the question where the build should fail. What about just moving the custom command to a new/separate custom target that has a dependency to `UnitTest`?

Comment: @Florian: `What about just moving the custom command to a new ...` - Then the effect of *POST_BUILD* command will be lost - running the test only if it is rebuilt. I think about the test (or wrapper around it) which produces some file instead of failing. Then another target, which runs unconditionally, may check files created by tests and return a verdict.

Comment: Running the tests even if the executable is not rebuilt is acceptable. It sounds like I will have to make another target. If somebody wants to make that into an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that I was alluding to was to use `add_custom_target` instead of `add_custom_command`.  While it will not delete the executable if the test fails and the build process as a whole fails if runUnitTest fails, this target does not get built as a result of building the UnitTest target specifically.

```
add_executable(UnitTest unittest.cpp)
add_custom_target(runUnitTest UnitTest COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:UnitTest> DEPENDS UnitTest)
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this same problem:  I have a unit test I only want to run in the following conditions:

1. The test has been modified.
2. The code under test has been modified.
3. The test failed its previous execution.

In the event the test is run and fails I want the test binary to remain for debugging.

The solution I ended up with uses a flag file to indicate the test has run and no longer needs to execute again.  Note the flag must live in the binary directory so that other builds are not impacted.  However the WORKING_DIRECTORY is set so the test can access read-only data files relative to its source location.  Here's what it all looks like -- I stuck this in a macro so all my various unit tests can invoke this, the only input to the macro is the test executable:

```
set (TEST_FLAG_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${TEST_EXECUTABLE}.PASSED)

# This isn't normally needed since a rebuild will have a newer time stamp.
# But it adds robustness to handle changes to the system clock.
add_custom_command(TARGET ${TEST_EXECUTABLE} 
    COMMENT "Unit test ${TEST_EXECUTABLE} rebuilt; clearing flag ${TEST_FLAG_FILE}." 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove -f ${TEST_FLAG_FILE}
    POST_BUILD 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# This command only runs if the flag isn't present or is older than the executable.
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${TEST_FLAG_FILE}
    COMMENT "Unit Test Execution: ${TEST_EXECUTABLE}" 
    COMMAND ${TEST_EXECUTABLE}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${TEST_FLAG_FILE}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${TEST_EXECUTABLE} 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# Any "make all" will evaluate the preceding custom command.
add_custom_target(run_${TEST_EXECUTABLE} ALL DEPENDS ${TEST_FLAG_FILE})
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Instead of `MAIN_DEPENDENCY` it's possible to simply use `DEPENDS` on a target, and then both `TEST_EXECUTABLE` and `TEST_FLAG_FILE` can be based on that target with generator expressions (`set (TEST_FLAG_FILE $<TARGET_FILE:MyTarget>.PASSED)` etc.). Then `WORKING_DIRECTORY` is no longer needed.