# add_custom_command: Remove redirected output on failure

Tags: cmake, ninja, build-system, cmake-custom-command

Consider the following custom command (latest CMake + ninja):

```
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT
            ${OUTPUT}
        COMMAND
            ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} script.py ${INPUT} > ${OUTPUT}
        DEPENDS
            ${INPUT}
        VERBATIM
        COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
    )
```

When `script.py` runs without errors, it works fine.

However, when `script.py` fails with an error, `${OUTPUT}` is still created.
So current build fails as expected but next build sees `${OUTPUT}` newer than `${INPUT}` and does not try to run the custom command again as it should.

I would expect the build system to automatically delete `${OUTPUT}` when the command fails, to prevent such case, but apparently this does not happen.

- Is there a way to perform an action "on failure" of a custom command?
  If there was, I could delete `${OUTPUT}` there.
- Alternatively, what is the simplest way to prevent output creation unless command succeeds?

I've tried naively to do something like:

```
${Python3_EXECUTABLE} script.py ${INPUT} > ${OUTPUT} || rm -f ${OUTPUT}
```

But that doesn't work because the command result code is in fact the `rm` result code instead of Python's result code, therefore the custom command doesn't fail as it should on a subsequent build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost there, just add **after** `rm` a command, which would return an error code. E.g. that way:

```
${Python3_EXECUTABLE} script.py ${INPUT} > ${OUTPUT} || (rm -f ${OUTPUT} && /bin/false)
```

With such command `VERBATIM` option for `add_custom_command` should NOT be used: With that option CMake quotes the brackets (`(` and `)`), which prevents a shell to interpret them for grouping purposes.

---

> I would expect the build system to automatically delete ${OUTPUT} when the command fails

Note, that CMake by itself is NOT a build system, it just generates a code for the build system.

As example, when CMake generates a Makefile, it [adds .DELETE_ON_ERROR target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41642161/3440745), so `make` utility actually deletes output files on failure.

It seems, that Ninja doesn't have such functionality as Make does. Or CMake doesn't use this functionality when generate a code for Ninja.

Comment: Adding `(rm -f ${OUTPUT} && /bin/false)` doesn't work because cmake doesn't process the `(` correctly: `/bin/sh: 1: (: not found`. Also tried to escape it `\(` or quote it but still not working.

Comment: Yes, CMake is "oversmart" with escaping/quoting things... Probably, removing `VERBATIM` from the `add_custom_command` call should help.

Comment: Removing `VERBATIM` helped. The command line becomes very long, is there a way to line break the command before `||`? Tried escaping line ending `\\` and tried putting the whole command in a multi-line string, both didn't work.

Comment: You could create a helper script (in bash, in python, etc.) which will be called like `redirect_output_smart.sh ${OUTPUT} ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} script.py ${INPUT}`. The script would call the wrapped command with and redirect its output into given file. If the command fails, the script would remove that file.